# Laravel 8 returns 404 Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, slug

I'm making a forum with Laravel 8, and basically whenever a user asks a question on this forum, it should be redirected to the question.

And I also want to make the redirection process based on the `slug` field of the question.

So in order to do this, I added this at the end of `postForm()` method:

`return redirect('questions/{slug}');`

And here is the route for seeing the question:

`Route::get('questions/{slug}' , [QuestionController::class, 'showQuestion']);`

And then I coded at the Controller:

```
public function showQuestion($slug)
    {
        $show = Question::find($slug);

        if(is_null($show)){
            abort(404);
        }

        return view('questions.question',[
            'show' => $show
        ]);
    }
```

But now the problem is, when I try to add a new question, the question will successfully added but it redirects me to `404` page. And the URL also looks like this after redirection:

`http://localhost:8000/questions/%7Bslug%7D`

However, if I try to add a `slug` - that already exists in db - manually after the `/questions/`, I still get the same `404` error!

So what's going wrong here? How can I properly redirect user to that route by `slug` of each question?

I would really appreciate if you help me out with this...

Comment: You need to put the actual slug you want to redirect to in `redirect('questions/{slug}')`  not instead of `{slug}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you can do.

1. You can change yours routes as below

   Route::get('questions/{question:slug}' , [QuestionController::class, 'showQuestion']

in your controller you can use dependency injection as below

```
public function showQuestion(Question $question)
{
  
    return view('questions.question',[
        'show' => $question
    ]);
}
```

2. You can change your query from find to where

public function showQuestion($slug)
{

```
    $show = Question::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    if(is_null($show)){
        abort(404);
    }

    return view('questions.question',[
        'show' => $show
    ]);
}
```